# Change markup field tekst during validation

Tags: drupal-6, webforms, validation

I have a webform with a custom calidator function. in the form is a markup field. How can I change the markup text in my validation hook if there is an error ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do! Could you give me an example for your case?! Or a copy of your code.

Comment: I just want to change some data in the $form variable during validation, but hook_form_alter is called before validation, and in the "validation_hook" the $form is a reference but a copy, so I can't alter anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok When going trough the flow, I found out somehere the variables are not passed as references, so you lose the information, I changed the this too be references, now it works

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this so you will have to test it yourself but...

If validation fails, then the form is typically displayed again with an error message added.  In which case, `hook_form_alter` will be called again *after* the validation.

Try setting a flag in the `$form_state` during your validation that you can check in your `hook_form_alter` to determine whether or not you should change the markup.

Comment: That is the weird part. When validation failes, hook_form_alter isn't called again.